# I can't find a way out of the infinite loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i am using a `useState()` function, an array `errors[]` that is part of state like this and a function `setError()` to pass the useState() function to child elements and call it from there:

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
const setError = (courses, day, hour) => {
  if (courses.length > 1) {
    console.log(day, hour);
  }
};
```

What am i doing here is, i pass the some information to `Schedule` component which is in App.js, from there to `Hour` components and within hour components to `Day` components that is nested in hour components.

```
<div className="wrapper">
  <h2>Schedule</h2>
  <Schedule setError={setError} courses={pickedCourses} />
</div>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
import Hour from "./Hour"

import React from 'react'

const Schedule = ({ courses, setError }) => {
    return (
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Friday</th>
                <th>Saturday</th>
                <th>Sunday</th>
            </tr>
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"08:30"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("08:30")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"09:20"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("09:20")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"10:10"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("10:10")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"11:00"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("11:00")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"11:50"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("11:50")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"12:40"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("12:40")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"13:30"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("13:30")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"14:20"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("14:20")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"15:10"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("15:10")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"16:00"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("16:00")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"16:50"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("16:50")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"17:40"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("17:40")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"18:30"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("18:30")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"19:20"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("19:20")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"20:10"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("20:10")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"21:00"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("21:00")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"21:50"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("21:50")))} />
            <Hour setError={setError} hour={"22:40"} course={courses.filter(i => i.time.some(j => j.includes("22:40")))} />
        </table>
    )
}

export default Schedule

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
import Day from "./Day"

import React from 'react'

const Hour = ({ hour, course, setError }) => {
    return (
        <tr>
            <th>{hour}</th>
            <Day setError={setError} hour={hour} day={"Pazartesi"} courses={course.filter(i=>i.time.some(j=>j.includes(hour)&&j.includes("Pazartesi")))} />
            <Day setError={setError} hour={hour} day={"Salı"} courses={course.filter(i=>i.time.some(j=>j.includes(hour)&&j.includes("Salı")))} />
            <Day setError={setError} hour={hour} day={"Çarşamba"} courses={course.filter(i=>i.time.some(j=>j.includes(hour)&&j.includes("Çarşamba")))} />
            <Day setError={setError} hour={hour} day={"Perşembe"} courses={course.filter(i=>i.time.some(j=>j.includes(hour)&&j.includes("Perşembe")))} />
            <Day setError={setError} hour={hour} day={"Cuma"} courses={course.filter(i=>i.time.some(j=>j.includes(hour)&&j.includes("Cuma")))} />
            <Day setError={setError} hour={hour} day={"Cumartesi"} courses={course.filter(i=>i.time.some(j=>j.includes(hour)&&j.includes("Cumartesi")))} />
            <Day setError={setError} hour={hour} day={"Pazar"} courses={course.filter(i=>i.time.some(j=>j.includes(hour)&&j.includes("Pazar")))} />
        </tr>
    )
}

export default Hour
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
import React from 'react'

const Day = ({ hour, day, courses, setError }) => {
    setError(courses, day, hour);
    return (
        <td style={courses.length > 1 ? {backgroundColor: "red"} : null} >{courses.length > 0 ? courses[0].code : null}</td>
    )
}

export default Day
```

So what i am trying to do is if there is 2 or more objects passed in the Day component's courses parameter, send some information to the errors array by setting the App component's state. But when i try this, Day component re-renders because i used the setState() function in that component and because it still has 2 or more objects as it's courses parameter, setState() triggers again which causes the re-render again and an infinite loop. I changed inside of the setError() function to a console.log() function to see if it's functioning properly and it is. It only triggers once and prints out just the info i need. Problem is about setState() function and it's re-render effect which is triggered on the object it's called. I need the setState() called only once when the courses parameter which is passed to Day object changes. How can i change my code in order to have the desired effect?

After using useEffect() in my Day component i have solved the issue with endless loop but now i have a problem which is setState() function in my code which is setErrors() doesn't trigger first time the conditions of the if block met. That's can be seen when the first courses.length exceeds the threshold 1 it returns a empty array even if i added a 1 to the array, but the second time and after that it works normally.

[image: Problem output]

I found out this was happening because setState is asynchronous and can't keep up with console.log()'s speed. The answer below is the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your infinite loop happens because you are calling `setError` in the render method of the `Day` component.  It will indeed update the app state, but then all the children will re-render, including the `Day` component.  Then what happens?  You guessed it, `setError` is called again, and we loop, and loop, and loop.

Perform the check for `if (courses.length > 1)` inside the `Day` component as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (courses.length > 1) setError(courses, day, hour);
}, [courses.length])
```

Because of the dependency array, this will only run when courses.length changes, including the first render.  So the first time it will check if the length is greater than 1, set the error, and on that following render will not run again.  Infinite loop avoided.

Comment: This seems to work but now i have another problem. When the condition of if first returns true and setError executed, setState function inside the setError function doesn't trigger but all other functions like console.log triggers normally. When the condition returns true for the second time and after that, setState function seems to work. What can be done about it? I added the current output to the post to help.

Comment: Ok, on my following checks i found up because setState is asynchronous, console.log() can't keep up with it and doesn't show the correct results. In other words, your solution works, thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry for spam but i have again a problem with your solution. In my case i send multiple setState requests at the same time but i figured out that only the last setState request (i mean the setState function with the parameters of the last component called) triggers and affects my state array. While i should get multiple inputs at once in the array, i get only one input and that always be the last component's parameters. Do you have a suggestion against that problem?

Comment: Yes! Consider the use of the most current state that is passed as an argument in the setter.  For instance: `setSomething((mostCurrent) => do something with mostCurrent)`  If you do it this way each call will always have the most up-to-date state.  The implementation might be: `setError((errors) => [...errors, newError])`

Comment: Thanks again. You helped me a lot to get to the solution. I was passing a setError function to the Day component and that function was containing setErrors function which is setState function of errors state array. I changed this and directly passed the setErrors function, which is setState function, to my components and changed the previous state using an arrow function like you showed. This fully solved my problems.

Comment: Happy to help :)